# Can't change my partition size through GParted

Tags: partitioning

So I've moved my linux swap partition out of the way, but I still can't extend my `/dev/sda5` for some reason? Relatively new to Linux so not sure whats going on.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Are you booted on a live flash drive/ CD?

Comment: No. I moved the swap partition, and now i can't boot unless i do it via recovery mode, and also still can't change my partition size.

Comment: `sudo resize2fs /dev/sda5` tried this?

Comment: When i tried that i just got                                                                               
"resize2fs 1.42.13 (17-May-2015)
The filesystem is already 4600576 (4k) blocks long.  Nothing to do!"

Answer (score 0):

The screenshot shows that sda5 is in use and thus preventing changes to the partition.   I suggest you boot from live media such as [GParted Live](http://gparted.org/livecd.php), which will not mount the partitions.  Then you should be able to resize/move sda5.  Note that if you move the start of the partition then you may need to restore the ability to boot.  See [GParted FAQ](http://gparted.org/faq.php#faq-6).

Comment: Thanks, i worked it out last night and this was in-fact the answer!